# Redirection to a variable has weird behaviour

Tags: bash, io

I have this small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in "$(ls | grep -v $0)";do
        cat $file > "${file}-test"
done
```

On this directory:

```
total 40
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   783 Dec 11 09:19 appendToLog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3995 Dec 11 13:22 con2dd.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   362 Dec 11 13:26 dd.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   566 Dec 11 13:26 dd.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18558 Dec 25 11:24 moshe.log
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Dec 11 09:20 nohup.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    88 Dec 25 11:28 task.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   560 Dec 11 10:33 test.py
```

Nevermind that I can achieve that with `cp`, I want to understand why this exactly is producing this file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24912 Dec 25 11:28 appendToLog.sh?con2dd.py?dd.py?dd.pyc?moshe.log?nohup.out?task.sh?test.py-test
```

And nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is parsing output of `ls` is just wrong (see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), filenames in unix can have almost any special characters including whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols. Its because you've quoted the output of `ls` in one construct, you have a single list of all the files concatenated as one string in the value of `"${file}-test"` which is quite *not* what you wanted to do.

Also notice how ls sometimes garbles your filename data (in our case, it turned the `\n` character in between the words into a `?` question mark (could indicate a character that cannot be displayed).

Just use the glob expansion in `bash` to list the files and do *actions* on them.

```
for f in *; do
    [[ -e $f ]] || continue
    ...
done
```

---

That said, You could probably have some non-printable characters on end of lines (eg. CRLF imported rom Windows)

Run `cat -A scriptname` it'll show you all characters in your script. Then, you can convert to unix-like format running `dos2unix scriptname`.